# Difference between Random and RandomGenerator

Tags: java, class, random

Main class for this project is `acm.program.GraphicsProgram;` [GraphicsProgram](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html)

When working on my project earlier i needed to randomize ball movement slightly in Pong game and found solution to this by using `import java.util.Random;` and then i used this code (executed every time ball bounces off player's paddle, this makes the ball move differently every game):

```
Random rand = new Random();
            boolean bool = rand.nextBoolean();
            if (bool)
                if (dx > 0)
                    dx += 1;
                else
                    dx -= 1;
            else if (dy > 0)
                    dy += 0.5;
                 else
                    dy -= 0.5;
```

where `dx` and `dy` are respectively ball horizontal and veritcal speeds.

But today during lecture on university we've been shown different method (not related to the 1st one, i figured that one myself earier), using

`import acm.util.RandomGenerator;`

and then

```
RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
boolean bool = rgen.nextBoolean();
```

Is there any difference between these two classes (Random and RandomGenerator)? If so, which one is better to use? I don't quite understand what `getInstance();` is and why I didn't need one when using `Random` class.

Comment: The standard one (java.util) has javadoc. The non-standard one (acm.util) should also have javadoc. If it has one, read it and compare it with the standard one. If it doesn't have one, then you should probably not use it.

Comment: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/util/RandomGenerator.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ACM `RandomGenerator` has a few extra conveniences methods, like `nextColor()` to pick a random color.

It also provides a global generator, via its `getInstance()` class method. Based on the comments, it sounds like the constructor uses the current time as a seed. This is a big flaw, and can result in a bug where different generator instances produce the same sequence of random numbers. To work around this, they recommend using just one instance of `RandomGenerator`, accessed via the `getInstance()` method.

In general, it would be best to use `java.util.Random`, because it doesn't introduce a third-party dependency in your program, and it uses a better seeding algorithm that isn't subject to the flaws of the ACM implementation.

Comment: Additionally, `java.util.Random` documents that it's using a linear congruential generator.  Whatever the ACM one is, it's not stated in the javadocs and might change.

Comment: Can we discuss why using the time as a seed is a flaw?  What else could you use as a seed that wouldn't potentially result in the same seed?

Comment: @dckuehn There's a finite resolution on most clocks, so it's easy to create multiple generators at the "same" time. Currently, `java.util.Random` combines the (high-resolution) time with a global MLCG output to make duplication of the seed astronomically improbable. Earlier versions simply used the low-resolution time and suffered the same problem described in the `RandomGenerator` documentation. Cryptographic RNGs, however, shouldn't use the time; they should use the system's entropy gathering device, which might be a quantum mechanical process, or collected from timings of system activity.